# Map resultset to non-entity Spring data Jpa

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Batch application and need to make a select from 4 tables. The problem, that i cant use relations, and will write enrichers to select full data.

Currently i have few problems:

1. Is it possible to map non entity (POJO) from **JpaRepository** in simple way. I seen examples with `@SqlResultSetMapping`. I am looking for auto mapping (Maybe JPA, not Spring Data). Column names i can make exacly with result, but it is not working.
2. It is no problem to mark POJO as Entity, but there is problem. Entity requires `@Id`. And this is problem for me, as my enrich data not suitable for this.

Maybe someone will give me tips, which better to use.
My perfect purpose is do something like this.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT id as main_id FROM table where name = ?1",
      nativeQuery = true)
  List<Data> getAll(String name);
And get objects mapped to my POJO.
```

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JPA constructor expression:

Example:

```
public class CallStatistics {

    private final long count;
    private final long total;
    private final int min;
    private final int max;
    private final double avg;

    public CallStatistics(long count, long total, int min, int max, double avg) {
        this.count = count;
        this.total = total;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.avg = avg;
    }

    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}

CallStatistics callStatistics = entityManager.createQuery(
    "select new org.hibernate.userguide.hql.CallStatistics(" +
    "   count(c), " +
    "   sum(c.duration), " +
    "   min(c.duration), " +
    "   max(c.duration), " +
    "   avg(c.duration)" +
    ")  " +
    "from Call c ", CallStatistics.class)
.getSingleResult();
```

The importants part are:

- You must have a class with a matching constructor
- You must use NEW followed by the fully qualified class name of the class

From: 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select-clause